# A question on pure math research for integer factorization

Tags: number-theory

I'm interested in integer factorization for a project I'm working on (no it doesn't involve RSA) and I've notice that the majority of papers seemed to be focused on algorithms. Applications aside, I haven't seen a great deal of recent theoretical work on factorization.

If someone could link a few papers focusing on the theory of factorization instead of algorithms, then I'd be most appreciative.

Edit:

First, it seems I accidently deleted the well thought out and rigorous reply. I am truly sorry and I hope that it can be recovered. My apologizes.

Second, let me refine my query a bit. I am research patterns of integer factorization looking for a general recursive relationship: give an integer factorization M for an arbitrary integer N, what can we say about N+1's factorization?

Most IF research is focused on finding particular IFs to break the RSA cryptosystem. I could care less about the speed of factorization as I'm looking for general results to help me prove something related to IF.

Answer (score 2):

Given the factorization of $n$, we can say next-to-nothing about the factorization of $n+1$. We can say no prime that divides $n$ also divides $n+1$; we can say that if $2$ doesn't divide $n$, then it does divide $n+1$; that's about it. If, say, $n$ is prime, $n+1$ could have hundreds of factors, or it could be twice a prime.

Comment: That's the point. There has to be some body of research attempting to say something

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson, no, there really doesn't. The idea you have described does not go anywhere. Meanwhile, you mentioned, in edit, something you want to prove about integer factorization. Why do you believe that item to be true?

Comment: first, please lay off the condescending attitude. There has been over 2000 years of research studying IF. Yes you can say some things. Second, I have significant numerical evidence to suggest what I'm trying to prove is true (up to 4 X 10^18). Third, most research papers study efficient algorithms thus making it difficult to find papers focusing on certain patterns outside the work of Hardy and Tao.

Comment: Furthermore, prime numbers do not exhibit a random distribution therefore it stands to reason that factorization patterns are also not random. I understand the difficulty in saying interesting things about them, yet one really could if he wanted. If you don't know, then just say so. Please don't just shoot me down and offer no help.

Comment: Charles, this would go better if you would lay your cards on the table and tell us what you know instead of hinting at it obscurely. It's hard to offer you help when you clearly have something specific in mind but refuse to let us in on it.

Comment: I found a pattern while studying the goldbach conjecture that relies upon a certain feature of certain factorizations. It's very easy to test and has held for an enormous set of numbers thus I believe it is interesting to study.

After exploring it for a bit, I was able to build a bound based on the product sequence of gaps between the greatest and lowest prime in a related factorization of 2n - (certain primes) thus showing any even number can be expressed as the sum of a prime and a finite product of primes. I want to reduce the finite product to one obviously, but I need more info on IF.

Comment: As I have reduced the problem to finite sets of a certain structure, I already know a great deal about the particular factorizations. I just need to know how they could change under addition within my finite range. I've constructed some rings to study the structure, but nothing obvious has occurred to me yet

Comment: And I'm sorry Will for being snippy, but as an MSRI mathematician you know that some things can be said about factorization outside of an O() algorithm. For example, any researcher studying the collatz conjecture eventually stumbles upon the realization that if one reaches a 2^n factorization from an arbitrary one in a finite sequence of steps, then the problem is resolved. In essence it is a problem about movement around particular factorizations.

Comment: "any even number can be expressed as the sum of a prime and a finite product of primes." Since every number can be expressed as a finite product of primes, it's not clear how this is progress. Perhaps you mean there is an absolute constant $k$ such that every even is a sum of a prime and a product of at most $k$ primes. Even there, I think this has been known, with $k=2$, for 40 years now. But it's all about sieve methods, and beyond my expertise, so I doubt I can offer much help.

Comment: You're rght that I've reproved results from hardy and chen but using a bounding argument that lets me generate specific sets of solutions. I'm thinking I can use fermats last theorem to reduce r to 2. But here is the cool part, there appears to be a way of showing one of the pairs can't be a pythagorean triple. Thus r=1

Comment: "any even number can be expressed as the sum of a prime and a finite product of primes" Let me refine what I meant to say. I proved any even number  can be expressed as the sum of a prime p and the product of the same prime q (2n = p + q^r) where q is prime. This is not a restatement of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "one of the pairs can't be a pythagorean triple," since I don't know what pairs you refer to and I don't see how a pair could possibly be a triple. You are claiming to have proved that every even number is a prime plus a power of a prime?

Comment: Yes I have and I'm not going to discuss what I mean by pair outside saying that a pair is a set of two numbers (p,q^r) such that p + q^r = 2n for any integer >= 8. Raise p to the r power and you can generate p^r + q^r = a^r and show that there exists a pair where a is an integer. Therefore, r <= 2. Show that one of these pairs cannot be a pythagorean triple. Therefore r is equal to 1

Comment: p and q are also prime I should mention

Comment: I'm trying to use Wiles work on fermat's last theorem to force my power of primes exponent to 2 or 1. The key is further forcing the exponent to 1 by eliminating the 2 case for some pair. I think this part is trivial compared to application of Fermat's last theorem, which requires very powerful machinery involving elliptic curves.

Comment: To clarify the triple component, in my construction, p^r + q^r = a^r yield triple (p,q,a). I assert you cannot form a Pythagorean triple out of at least one of these sets. thus r = 1 and from our prior knowledge p + q^r = 2n implying a = 2n

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. Here's an old exchange between Charles Hoskinson, who's literally changing the world and the whole planet as we speak right now with Cardano and ADA and on the other side someone who's very condescending and who likely has had none to very little positive impact on society as a whole trying to snuff out curiosity, innovation and genius. Shows you something's deeply off. Hindsight is 20/20...

Comment: @Rachid, do you know whether CH has ever gotten anywhere with what he was writing about in this discussion? Did he ever publish anything about his discoveries on integer factorization, or settle Goldbach's problem? What he has done with cryptocurrencies – does it have any bearing on the discussion here?